# Invalid Syntax error python 3.5.2

Tags: python, python-3.x, syntax

I'm getting syntax error in this particular line.

```
print "Sense %i:" %(i),
```

**Full code:**

```
for i in range(len(meas)):
    p = sense(p, meas[i])
    r = [format(j,'.3f') for j in p]
    print "Sense %i:" % (i),
    print r,
    entropy(p)
    p = move(p, mov[i])
    r = [format(j,'.3f') for j in p]
    print "Move %i:" % (i),
    print r,
    entropy(p)
    print
```

Comment: Which is the version of Python you're using? If it's Python 3 your code will have to look like this: `print("Sense %i:" % (i), end="")`.

Comment: When i try making changes in the code i get error in next line

Comment: In that case you might be missing a closing parentheses in the line before this.

Comment: for i in range(len(meas)):
    p = sense(p, meas[i])
    r = [format(j,'.3f') for j in p]
    print "Sense %i:"%(i),
    print r, entropy(p)
    p = move(p, mov[i])
    r = [format(j,'.3f') for j in p]
    print "Move  %i:"%(i),
    print r, entropy(p)
    print

Comment: What is the error message?  Post the **full** stack trace.

Answer (score 1):

Several things:

- In Python 3, `print` is a function, no more a statement like it was with Python 2. So, you need to add parenthesis to call the function,
- the `%` operator used for string formatting is deprecated. With Python 3, you should use the `format` method (or the `format` function),
- the `%` operator usually take a `tuple` as a second parameter: the expression "(i)" is not a `tuple` but a constant. With Python, the singleton `tuple` has a trailing comma like this: "(i,)".
- use the keyword argument `end=""` to replace the newline by an empty string (but I'm not sure this is what you want)

So, you can replace your code by:

```
print("Sense {}:".format(i), end="")
```

**EDIT: add code from comment**

Your code should be converted in Python 3 like bellow:

```
for i in range(len(meas)):
    p = sense(p, meas[i])
    r = [format(j,'.3f') for j in p]
    print("Sense {0}:".format(i), end="")
    print(r, end="")
    entropy(p)
    p = move(p, mov[i])
    r = [format(j,'.3f') for j in p]
    print("Move {0}:".format(i), end="")
    print(r, end="")
    entropy(p)
    print()
```

Comment: for i in range(len(meas)):
    p = sense(p, meas[i])
    r = [format(j,'.3f') for j in p]
    print "Sense %i:"%(i),
    print r, entropy(p)
    p = move(p, mov[i])
    r = [format(j,'.3f') for j in p]
    print "Move  %i:"%(i),
    print r, entropy(p)
    print

Comment: Thanks a lot !!! it works perfectly fine now... Actually i am just beginner in python programming. I would like to know if you can help me with other codes. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
print ("Sense %s:" %i)
```

Will work just fine

Answer (score 0):

In python 3, print is a function, you have to use brackets: `print("Sense %i:" %(i))`

Comment: print ("Sense %i:"%(i))
    print r, entropy(p)
    p = move(p, mov[i])
    r = [format(j,'.3f') for j in p]
    print "Move  %i:"%(i),
    print r, entropy(p)